# Android Studio - I cant use intent in realtime database Fire base

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

I try to use an intent from a previous activity to see infromation from my database but when i try to do it i get this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" so i don't know how to proceed, this right here is my code:

```
package es.ua.eps.automatismos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Space;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Saldo extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTV;
    String spLine;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);
        Intent I = getIntent();
         spLine = I.getStringExtra("SC");

    mTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saldo);
}
    DatabaseReference mDBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mRC = mDBR.child(spLine);
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mRC.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override

            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Money = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                mTV.setText(Money);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the complete error log and where the error point so we can easily help you

Comment: Please share the code from the first activity where you are adding the data to the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You call `DatabaseReference mRC = mDBR.child(spLine)` outside of onCreate(), so spLine has not been initialized yet. You can rewrite the code like this:

```
public class Saldo extends AppCompatActivity {
        private TextView mTV;
        String spLine;
        DatabaseReference mDBR;
        DatabaseReference mRC;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);

            Intent I = getIntent();
            spLine = I.getStringExtra("SC");

            mDBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mRC = mDBR.child(spLine);

            mTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saldo);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            mRC.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override

                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String Money = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    mTV.setText(Money);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```